# How to return custom status code via DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If a user sends a POST request to create a job, but that job already exists - I am trying to return a 202.

Instead, it is returning a 400..

views

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = CreateJobSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer

```
class CreateJobSerializer(GenericSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('name')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            obj = Job.objects.create(**validated_data)
            return obj
        except:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

I assume that Job.objects.create will fail if unique=true is violated on that model, if that is the case I would expect a 202 to be returned.  What am I doing wrong?

Is it because the unique=true error is actually being caught during validation so create() is never actually called?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can [capture the Validation Error](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data) and then make a custom response with the status you want (202 in this case).

I haven't tried it but this may work:

```
try:
    if (serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)):
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
except ValidationError as msg:
    if str(msg) == "This Email is already taken":
        return Response(
            {'ValidationError': str(msg)},
            status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED
        )
    else:
        return Response(
            {'ValidationError': str(msg)},
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
```

Comment: where does msg come from?

Comment: It's the variable where i save the `Exception`. This is the same as `except ValidationError as msg` but in an older version of python. I changed the code.

Comment: i don't think this works - I don't think I was ever getting a ValidationError, I am getting non_field_errors